# Topology and the arbitrary union requirement

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I'm just trying to go through Munkres' topology. From what I understood so far, when proving that a certain collection $\mathscr T$ is a topology on a set $X$, one of the things that has to be shown is that

$$\textrm{If $\mathscr A \subseteq \mathscr T$ then $\bigcup_{A\in \mathscr A}A \in \mathscr T$ }$$

My question is, is there really any need to show this? I mean, isn't $\bigcup_{A\in \mathscr A}A  $ just equal to $\mathscr A$? So if $\mathscr A$ is a subset of $\mathscr T$, then all $x \in \mathscr A$ is automatically in $\mathscr T$.

Comment: Did you read the introductory chapter in Munkres discussing the set theory?

Comment: Suppose $\mathscr A$ is a hockey league. If $A\in  \mathscr A$ then $A$ is a hockey team, and any $p\in A$ is a player. The $definition$ of $\cup \mathscr A$ (that is, of $\cup_{A\in \mathscr A}A$), is the set of all players in the league:... $p\in\cup \mathscr A \iff \exists A\in \mathscr A\,(p\in A)$. That is, $\cup\mathscr A$ is the set of the members of the members of $\mathscr A$.

Answer (score 1):

> isn't $\bigcup_{A\in \mathscr A}A  $ just equal to $\mathscr A$?

No. Consider $\mathscr A = \{\{\}\}$, which yields $\{\}$.

Or $\mathscr A = \{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$, which yields $\{1,2\} \cup \{3,4\} = \{1,2,3,4\}$.

More generally,

$$\bigcup_{A \in \{B_1, B_2, B_3, \ldots\}} A = B_1 \cup B_2 \cup B_3 \cup \ldots \neq \{B_1, B_2, B_3, \ldots\}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\bigcup_{A\in\mathscr{A}}A\neq\mathscr{A}$$

The LHS means: the set of all $x$ such that there is at least one $A\in\mathscr{A}$ with $x\in A$. The RHS means: the set of all $A\in\mathscr{A}$. These are not the same. For example, if $\mathscr{A}=\{\{0,1\},\{2,3,4\}\}$, the LHS is: $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. The RHS is the sets $\{0,1\}$, $\{2,3,4\}$.

For example, if $\mathscr{T}=\{\{0,1\},\{2,3,4\},\{5\}\}$ and we consider the base set $X$ to be $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$, and $\mathscr{A}=\{\{0,1\},\{2,3,4\}\}$ as before, the union is: $$\{0,1,2,3,4\}\notin\mathscr{T}$$

So this is genuinely a nontrivial axiom.